# How to correctly identify d-separation in directed graphical model (DGM)?

Tags: graphical-model, bayesian-network

Pardon me for the newbie question, I'm new in Bayesian network.

I'm reading Chapter 10, Directed Graphical Models (Bayes nets), of Kevin Murphy's textbook: *Machine Learning, a Probabilistic Perspective*.

Some discussion about using **Bayes ball algorithm** to test if d-separation holds between two nodes X, Y (or two sets of nodes X, Y) is not clear to me.

For example, the first figure below indicates that node X and node Z are not d-separated.

However, the rule corresponding to the boundary case (second figure below) suggests that the path between nodes x and z is blocked.

[image]

So, my question is, if X in the first figure is observed, are Y and Z d-separated then (since the case will be reduced to the second figure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO. If $Y$ is not observed, $X$ and $Z$ are not d-separated. The ball can simply pass through $Y$ and reach to $Z$.

Note that the second figure does not mean that the path between nodes $x$ and $z$ is blocked. It means that if $z$ is an unobserved leaf, the ball cannot pass through $z$, that is the ball cannot bounce back to $x$. It is defined to ensure that if none of the descendants of a v-structure is observed, the ball does not bounce back.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @hossein! I think what I don't fully understand is, if I focus on Y and Z nodes in the third figure above, I don't see any [Bayes ball rules](http://ai.stanford.edu/~paskin/gm-short-course/lec2.pdf) that tell me how to determine d-separation in that situation, although intuition tells me that Y and Z are not d-separated.

Comment: When you have $Y \rightarrow Z$, the nodes $Y$ and $Z$ cannot be d-separated at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [Moralized Ancestral Graph](http://web.mit.edu/jmn/www/6.034/d-separation.pdf).

> Let X, Y, and Z be variables in a graph. We say X is d-separated from
> Y given Z if X and Y are separated in the moralized ancestral graph.
> This graph is constructed by first removing the descendants of X, Y,
> Z. Then we convert the edges to undirected edges and add edges between
> nodes which have a common child in the original graph, but no edge
> between them.

Source: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10708-17/notes-17/10708-scribe-lecture2.pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Eepxing/Class/10708-17/notes-17/10708-scribe-lecture2.pdf)

In your case,
[image]
We first remove the descendants of X, Y, Z and get:
[image]
Then we convert the edges to undirected edges and obtain:
[image]
Then we add edges between nodes which have a common child in the original graph, but no edges between them(v-structure) and get:
[image]

We see that Y and Z are connected, and hence they are not d-separated.